# Unstack Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have seen a lots of similar questions over here, but unfortunately I was not able to find the answers that could help me.

What I'm trying to do is to reshape the DataFrame with MultiIndex via `unstack()` method. Here is it:

```
                                                                      val  
item  indicator                                                            
0     Расположение:                          Минское шоссе /Минское шоссе  
      Направление:                                                  Запад  
      Площадь:                                                    1200 м²  
      Стоимость:                                       1 007 259 000 руб.  
1     Расположение:                            Переделкино /Минское шоссе  
      Направление:                                                  Запад  
      Площадь:                                                     850 м²  
      Стоимость:                                         973 683 700 руб.  
2     Расположение:                                Бородки /Минское шоссе  
      Направление:                                                  Запад  
      Площадь:                                                     860 м²  
      Стоимость:                                         786 669 600 руб.
```

The desired output:

```
    Расположение:    Направление:    Площадь:    Стоимость:
0       ...             ...            ...          ...
1       ...             ...            ...          ...
2       ...             ...            ...          ...
```

I tried to use the unstack() according to the [manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking), but with no success:

```
In [6]: combined.unstack('indicator')
...
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As the error message says, you apparantly have duplicated values in the index, and `unstack` cannot handle these (multiple values to put at the same place). So you should first get handle the duplicate values yourself, or you could use `pivot_table` and specify how the duplicates should be aggregated.

Comment: You can chain a `.drop_duplicates()` call before the `unstack('indicator')` call if don't need to keep the duplicate indices.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, there were mistakes in my DataFrame. I missed them.